# Difference between `{id: 1, title: "text"}` and {title: "text", id: 1} MongoDB Indexes

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nosql

I am designing a schema where a `User` document stores the `Skill` ids. A `Skill` document look like this

```
Skill = {
  id: ObjectId
  title: String
  description: String
}

User = {
  id: ObjectId
  skills: [ObjectId]
}
```

And on the frontend side, a user can add `Skill`s by searching it's title. Therefore, I indexed skills collection by `{id: 1, title: "text"}`. I want to know whether ordering matters when we combine text indexes with the numeric ones.

Comment: Are you sure you need that id column in the index? Why not just the text index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it makes a big difference, the [documentation about composite text indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#compound-index) says

- If the compound text index includes keys preceding the text index key, to perform a `$text` search, the query predicate must include equality match conditions on the preceding keys.

That means if you do `{id: 1, title: 'text'}` you can only use the text index on title if you also constrain the search to within a *single* id.

If you do `{title: 'text', id: 1}` you will be able to text-search title by itself, or further constrained by id, or retrieve the matching id for the text search results.

Are you sure you need that `id` column in the index? Why not just the text index?

Comment: I thought it might be a good idea to include a `id` index, in case I want to access the document by its `id` only.

Comment: Have a separate index for that. Doesn't make sense to combine it with the text index.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does matter. Straight from the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/):

> The order of the fields listed in a compound index is important. The index will contain references to documents sorted first by the values of the item field and, within each value of the item field, sorted by values of the stock field. See Sort Order for more information.

In your current structure if you only query the `title` field without an restrictions (no query) on the `id` field you will not be able to utilize the index.

Comment: That section does not really apply to text indexes.

Comment: I want to implement a search through Skills collection, but right now I am thinking about first fetching all the `Skill` documents, store them in memory cache, and use **Fuse.js** to display suggestion